# PHP JSON Check if value exists

Tags: php, json

Ok so I have a JSON string looks like this.

```
{
    "1": [
        "a",
        "ab",
        "ac"
    ],
    "3": [
        "v",
        "aw",
        "ea"
    ],
    "4": [
        "ffg",
        "sd"
    ]
}
```

I decoded it with `json_decode($string, true);` Now, I need to find a way to check, for example, is `a` exists? If it exists, I want to know the name of its parent value(e.g. `1`). The keys and values aren't always the same, they will keep changing. Can anyone provide me an example code on how can I do this? Thanks in advanced ;)

Comment: What you have tried Jeremy ?

Comment: @CSGO I didn't try anything because I've no idea lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That string is gives me back `null`, if i tried to convert it to JSON, so i've just built an array to you for example. I've just create a function, and loop through on all the key of that. After that, in the sub array, loop through again to check the first occurence of the searched string. If you need all the results, then you can strore the keys in an array, and return with that.

```
//The string we search
$searchString = "aw";

//The array where we search
$array = array(
    "1" => array("a", "ab", "ac"),
    "3" => array("v", "aw", "ea"),
    "4" => array("ffg", "sd")
);


$result = getArrayIndex($array, $searchString);
if (empty($result)) {
    "I did not find your string: " . $searchString;
} else {
    echo "The index of your main array, where  '" . $searchString . "' found is: " . $result;
}

function getArrayIndex($array, $searchString) {
    if (count($array)) {
        foreach (array_keys($array) as $key) {
            if (is_array($array[$key])) {
                foreach ($array[$key] as $item) {
                    if ($item === $searchString) {
                        return $key;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: From `$array[$key] as $item`. But as i sad, your json string is invalid.

Comment: I've built in some protection. But if you run exactly my code, (with search string, and with my array, it should work!

Comment: I edited my JSON. I wrote it but didn't copy & paste but the JSON string looks like that.

Comment: Oh yea it works. I did some mistake ;)